# Finding the coordinates of the initial location in OSMDROID

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am using osmdroid and i am just having an issue with getting the coordinates of my initial location on the map.

I can get the location on the map and i can get the initial location to print inside the runable.

Is there any way i can get just the initial coordinates? I dont need to update them or anything..

I just need them so i can design a route between the initial location and the destination....

Any help would be great thanks!

Here is my code;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

        mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        IMapController mapController = mMapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(13);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(52.167247, -6.888583);

        Marker POI1 = new Marker(mMapView);
        Marker POI2 = new Marker(mMapView);
        Marker POI3 = new Marker(mMapView);
        Marker POI4 = new Marker(mMapView);


        POI1.setPosition(new GeoPoint(52.187668, -6.866953));
        POI2.setPosition(new GeoPoint(52.124359, -6.926442));
        POI3.setPosition(new GeoPoint(52.222310, -6.933613));
        POI4.setPosition(new GeoPoint(52.221245, -6.830961));

        List<OverlayItem> markers = null;


        mMapView.getOverlays().add(POI1);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(POI2);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(POI3);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(POI4);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);


        //add
        GpsMyLocationProvider provider = new GpsMyLocationProvider(this);

        provider.addLocationSource(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        locationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(provider, mMapView);
        locationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        locationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();


        locationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Log.d("MyTag", String.format("First location fix: %s", locationOverlay.getLastFix()));

            }
        });






        mMapView.getOverlayManager().add(locationOverlay);


        //System.out.println("hello joe: " + currentLocation.getLongitude() );
        RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(this);


        ArrayList<GeoPoint> wayPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

        wayPoints.add(startPoint);
        GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(52.221245, -6.830961);
        wayPoints.add(endPoint);

        Road road = roadManager.getRoad(wayPoints);

        if (road.mStatus !=  Road.STATUS_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error when loading road", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);


    }
```

Comment: Why don't you get a location from LocationProvider?

Comment: Thanks Andrey, yes I did that after not thinking about it all day. Working now and I feel quite silly 

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the location provider